# Can't install dotnet-symbol in docker

Tags: .net, .net-core

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-alpine
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-dump
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-symbol
```

And output from docker build command:

```
docker build -t dotnetdump .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.113MB
Step 1/3 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-alpine
 ---> c7bc3a292fb8
Step 2/3 : RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-dump
 ---> Running in 64fdd40c84ba
Tools directory '/root/.dotnet/tools' is not currently on the PATH environment variable.
If you are using bash, you can add it to your profile by running the following command:

cat << \EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
# Add .NET Core SDK tools
export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
EOF

You can add it to the current session by running the following command:

export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"

You can invoke the tool using the following command: dotnet-dump
Tool 'dotnet-dump' (version '6.0.257301') was successfully installed.
Removing intermediate container 64fdd40c84ba
 ---> d7c9621f15cc
Step 3/3 : RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-symbol
 ---> Running in 4e364c8c6e5e
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.403/NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Failed to retrieve information about 'dotnet-symbol' from remote source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/dotnet-symbol/index.json'. [/tmp/ngnhhqca.szt/restore.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.403/NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   Name does not resolve (api.nuget.org:443) [/tmp/ngnhhqca.szt/restore.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.403/NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   Name does not resolve [/tmp/ngnhhqca.szt/restore.csproj]
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'dotnet-symbol' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.

For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet tool install --global dotnet-symbol' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Why I can't install dotnet-symbol? It seems this is a dot-net tool and it does exist - I don't get it...

Using Docker Desktop 2.1.0.4 on MacOS

---

Edit: included output which verifies that docker can connect to nuget API:

```
$ docker build -t dotnetdump .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.113MB
Step 1/4 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine
 ---> 9d2c47a10a43
Step 2/4 : RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-dump
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2441676e9983
Step 3/4 : RUN curl https://api.nuget.org
 ---> Running in 01e48ec9ab73
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0   351    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidQueryParameterValue</Code><Message>Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.
RequestId:bc45b7b2-b01e-0018-32a8-f5ce11000000
100   351  100   351    0     0    542      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   542
Time:2021-12-20T13:50:40.5285563Z</Message><QueryParameterName>comp</QueryParameterName><QueryParameterValue /><Reason /></Error>Removing intermediate container 01e48ec9ab73
 ---> 8db3dda34a98
Step 4/4 : RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-symbol
 ---> Running in a417cb9965be
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101/NuGet.targets(130,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/tmp/oo0ekzsf.d50/restore.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101/NuGet.targets(130,5): error :   Name does not resolve (api.nuget.org:443) [/tmp/oo0ekzsf.d50/restore.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101/NuGet.targets(130,5): error :   Name does not resolve [/tmp/oo0ekzsf.d50/restore.csproj]
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'dotnet-symbol' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.

For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet tool install --global dotnet-symbol' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this part of the error message:

```
Name does not resolve (api.nuget.org:443)
```

Looks like your container can't connect to api.nuget.org. That's the problem you need to fix.

Can your container make any connections to `nuget.org`? Or any other website? Are you behind a firewall that blocks connections? Do you need to configure a proxy server?

Comment: I am not behind any kind of firewall, dotnet-dump installs correctly, and I dont have any problems with any other dockers connecting to internet.

Comment: Does a `RUN curl https://api.nuget.org` work if you put it in your dockerfile?

Comment: Yes it works - see update in my question. When calling `RUN curl https://api.nuget.org` it returns default error message from nuget api.